# DataFrame Pivot Table run specific function on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an dataset that includes the below information. I'd like to write a pivot table that counts the number of days from the Date Column, and then runs sum on the Impression, Clicks, Conversions, and Budget Delivered columns. Essentially, I'd like a summary of the table

```
Date    Impressions Clicks  Conversions Budget Delivered
0   1/1/2019    11,506,995  1,672   88  $12,124.14
1   1/2/2019    9,394,458   1,516   179 $9,838.45
2   1/3/2019    4,696,388   878 129 $6,858.67
3   1/4/2019    8,987,784   1,179   107 $9,566.55
4   1/5/2019    8,923,751   1,171   88  $9,322
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to return this single row DataFrame. I am trying to use pivot_table method but the groupby parameter is not returning the desired result. Not sure how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datatable import dt, f, by

df = dt.Frame("""
Date    Impressions Clicks  Conversions Budget Delivered
   1/1/2019    11,506,995  1,672   88  $12,124.14
   1/2/2019    9,394,458   1,516   179 $9,838.45
   1/3/2019    4,696,388   878 129 $6,858.67
   1/4/2019    8,987,784   1,179   107 $9,566.55
   1/5/2019    8,923,751   1,171   88  $9,322
""")

budget = df['Budget'].to_list()[0]
budget = [float(x.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')) for x in budget]

df['Budget'] = dt.Frame(budget)

df[:, dt.sum(f[1:6])]


   | Impressions  Clicks  Conversions   Budget  Delivered
-- + -----------  ------  -----------  -------  ---------
 0 |    43509376    6416          591  47709.8          0
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is string cleaning.  As it stands, your input DataFrame contains mostly strings because of the non-numeric characters like `/`, `,`, and `$`.  The first step is to clean the data and convert it to a summable type such as `int` or `float`.  Then we can sum all rows.

For non-numeric fields that should be counted rather than summed ('Date'), we replace those summed strings with counts.

Also, not sure you need a single row DataFrame when a Series would have sufficed, but since it was in the requirements I did that too.

It's inelegant, but it works:

```
def clean(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return(x.replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))
    return(x)


data_df['Budget Delivered'] = data_df['Budget Delivered'].apply(clean).astype('float')

col_names_to_intify = ['Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Conversions']
for col in col_names_to_intify:
    data_df[col] = data_df[col].apply(clean).astype('int')
    
sum_df = data_df.sum().to_frame().T
for col in data_df.columns:
    if data_df[col].dtypes.str == '|O':
        sum_df[col] = data_df[col].count()
```

which gives `sum_df` as

```
   Date Impressions Clicks Conversions Budget_Delivered
0     5    43509376   6416         591         47709.81
```